# Webix mobile calendar saving events to mysql database twice

Tags: webix

So am experimenting with Webix and so far I like it. Am playing around with the mobile calendar/scheduler and am getting stuck with saving new events into mysql database. I have followed the tutorials and docs about saving data to the database and indeed I am able to save new events. Problem is that it is saving the new events twice, and I have failed to figure out why. Here is the code:

```
webix.ready(function(){
        webix.ui.fullScreen();
        webix.ui({
        rows:[
            {
                view: "toolbar", id:"toolbar", elements:[
                {
                    view: "icon", icon: "bars",
                    click: function(){
                        if( $$("menu").config.hidden){
                            $$("menu").show();
                        }
                        else
                            $$("menu").hide();
                    }
                },
                {
                    view: "label",
                    label: "JPlan"
                }

            ]
            },
            {
                view: "scheduler",
                id: "scheduler",
                url: "data/getEvents.php",
                save:{
                    "insert":"data/saveEvents.php",
                    "update":"data/update.php",
                    "delete":"data/delete.php"
                }
            }
            ]

        });


    });
```

And the php code to save the new events:

```
<?php
include('mysql.class.php');

$db = new MySQL();

$values = array();

$now = time();


$values["eventTitle"]  = MySQL::SQLValue($_POST['text']);
$values["eventJudge"]  = MySQL::SQLValue($_POST['judge']);
$values["eventStart"]  = MySQL::SQLValue($_POST['start_date']);
$values["eventEnd"]  = MySQL::SQLValue($_POST['end_date']);
$values["eventNotes"]  = MySQL::SQLValue($_POST['details']);
$values["eventAddedTime"]  = MySQL::SQLValue($now);
$values["eventAddedBy"]  = MySQL::SQLValue('');


// Execute the insert 
$result = $db->InsertRow("tbl_events", $values);
?>
```

The app loads all events from the database well. It is just that when I save a new event, it saves the evet twice in the database. I have not yet worked on the update and delete code.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Client side code expects some valid JSON response from a server-side, as confirmation that the save operation was successful. Otherwise, a client-side code may make another attempt to save a data.

```
$result = $db->InsertRow("tbl_events", $values);
$id = get_id_of_new_record();
echo "{ id: $id }";
```

Comment: I have returned last inserted id as you suggested in JSON format, but there is no change. Still saving twice.